# Maven project works locally but not on docker compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a java project that I can run successfully by using

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

The same project run through docker compose using the following set of instructions will not run:

Inside docker-compose.yml:

```
project:
    build: ./project
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and inside the Dockerfile in the project directory:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./mvnw","spring-boot:run"]
```

Now the interesting part is that I am getting the following exception message when using docker-compose:

```
InvocationTargetException: Invalid bean definition with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [****/****/****/****/****/config/RedisContextConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=****.****.***.***.redis.config.RedisContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=redisTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [***/***/**/***/**/config/RedisContextConfiguration.class]] for bean 'redisTemplate': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfiguration; factoryMethodName=redisTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [***/****/***/***/config/AppConfiguration.class]]
```

I was getting the exact same error before, but I managed to avoid it by adding the following line to the application.properties file:

```
spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false
```

Now this tells me that somehow the changes made to application.properties are not being seen by docker-compose. Since the container can't run I cannot use docker exec to peruse the files inside and see what's inside the application.properties.

Is there a way to access this .properties inside the image that is being used to create the container, so that I can confirm my suspicions about the property not being there?
Might there be another reason why locally the project runs but not using docker?
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `docker run -it your_image_name sh` to get a shell that will help you expect your image content.
I see two environment variables, SERVER_PORT and APP_PROPERTIES in the docker command, but you did not declare them in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Dockerfile was referencing docker-application.properties instead of the application.properties file.